# Is it recommended to place a button next to iPhone X virtual home button?

Tags: ios, user-interface, ios11, iphone-x, mobile-development

[image]

[image]

Is it recommended to place a button next to the home button like Apple did it in the system weather app? I would suggest that in this area you should not place any control elements. I didn't find any Information about that topic in Apples iOS Interface Guidlines.

(And why are the paging-dots in different positions from time to time?)

Comment: The paging dots (and other bottom bar elements) shifting position in the Weather app looks like a bug. [I’d suggest reporting it](http://bugreport.apple.com).

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way is to place all UI elements inside the Safe Area. Please, see section **Inset essential content to prevent clipping** by the link [Human Interface Guidelines for iPhone X](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/overview/iphone-x/)

> Apps should adhere to the safe area and layout margins defined by
>   UIKit, which ensure appropriate insetting based on the device and
>   context. The safe area also prevents content from underlapping the
>   status bar, navigation bar, toolbar, and tab bar.

And also see the video [Designing for iPhone X](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/fall2017/801/). There is also some notes about Safe Area.